# How to make div's width to expand within scrollable content

Tags: html, css

A div's width is not expanding with the width of its parent container or its content. There are no floats involved. The parent div has `overflow:scroll` and `white-space:pre` set; all else is normal. Identical behavior observed in Firefox, IE/Edge, Opera, and Chrome.

```css
div.wrapper {
  padding: 1em;
  width: 20em;
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
  overflow: scroll;
  white-space: pre;
  font-family: monospace;
}
div.line {
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}
div.line span.blue {
  color: blue;
}
div.line span.green {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
  <div class='line'>This text is too <span class="blue">long</span> for the wrapper div to <span class="green">contain</span>, so the scroll bar activates.</div>
  <div class='line'>However, the line div's background color fails to <span class="blue">expand</span> with the longer contents, instead ending at the wrapper div's width. Why?</div>
</div>
```

The background color of `div.line` extends as far as `div.wrapper`'s width on the page. But, when the user scrolls right, the text appears as normal while the `div.line`'s background color ends.

What I need is for every `div.line` to be as wide as `div.wrapper`'s "inner" width (to fill the scrollable area).

Failed solutions:

- set `overflow:hidden` - this hides the overflowing content, instead of resizing the div
- set `overflow:auto` - this makes no difference
- add `<div style="clear:both"> </div>` - makes no difference (no floats involved!)
- set `after:...clear:both` - makes no difference, as above
- set height on parent / child elements - makes no difference
- set `width:auto` - made no difference

I've researched this until my brain hurts. I really hope I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it! This was a hard one and was starting to bother me so I had to solve it. Had to just mess around with some display values until it looks right. Also moved white-space prop to the line class. https://jsfiddle.net/0yr0xg35/1/

```
div.wrapper {
  padding: 1em;
  width: 20em;
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 240);
  overflow: scroll;
  font-family: monospace;
}
div.line {
  display: table-row;
  white-space: pre;
  background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}
div.line span.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
            div.wrapper {
                padding:1em;
                width:20em;
                background-color:rgb(240,240,240);
                overflow:scroll;
                white-space:pre;
                font-family:monospace;
            }
            div.line {
                background-color:rgb(200,200,200);
                width: 240vh;
            }
            div.line span.blue { color:blue; }
            div.line span.green { color:green; }
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
<div class='line'>This text is too <span class="blue">long</span> for the wrapper div to <span class="green">contain</span>, so the scroll bar activates.  </div>
<div class='line'>However, the line div's background color fails to <span class="blue">expand</span> with the longer contents, instead ending at the wrapper div's width. Why?</div>
</div>
```

Give your div some width mate. Try using: vh or vw instead of %.
Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Works fine on my end lol try full screen maybe? in your div.line add width 240vh. you might need to adjust the numbers to fit. That is all I added to your code mate.

Comment: Unfortunately, this cannot work for dynamic content or different users, since 240vh will produce a different size on every screen, and will never change with content width.

Comment: That is correct mate. This could be fixed with media queries lol or you could use vw instead which make it change depending on the width instead of height.  For example: you could add a font-size: 3vw; to the 'wrapper' and swap the 240vh to 240vw on the '.line'. This way everything will change even the content. All you would need to do is adjust font-size and width in media queries as even font-size: 3vw is small on a mobile, yet large on a medium sized laptop. It works fine dynamically mate pretty much everything I do is PHP. sorry for late reply.

Answer (score 0):

Change **width** to **min-width**:

```
min-width: 20em;
```

And remove:

```
white-space: pre;
```